# IQStreamable: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

Tags: c#, linq, streaminsight

I am using "System.Linq.Dynamic" package for preparing "WHERE" clause like below,

```
 var customers = GetCustomers().Where("OrderId > 100").ToList();
```

The above code work fine with plain "Customer" object, but when the same thing I am trying to do with **"IQStreamable" customer**, I am getting error,

```
cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ConsoleApp2.Customer, bool>>'
```

Code,

```
public IQStreamable<Object> Do(IQStreamable<Customer> source)
    {
        var test = from m in source.Where("OrderId > 100")
                   select m;
        return test;
    }
```

I believe the reason could be due to "IQStreamable" form of customer, Is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: The dynamic overloads applies only to `IQueryable`, not `IQStreamable`. And I doubt it would work due to how dynamic expressions work anyway. I suppose you could try to bridge the gap to make `IQStreamable` wrapped as an `IQueryable` but again, I doubt it would actually function like you would want it to.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Use 'using system.linq.expressions' in your libraries